# Jump in Extrinsic Curvature

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, branes

In the thin shell formalism, the components of the surface stress-energy tensor are found using the next equation:

\begin{equation}
S^{a}_{\, \, \, b} = const\left([K^{a}_{\, \, \, b}] - \delta^{a}_{\, \,\, b}[K] \right) ,\tag{12.125}
\end{equation}
where $K = h^{ab}K_{ab}$ and $[K] = K_{+} - K_{-} $ defines extrinsic curvature's jump.

Moreover, using the following equations, one can easily encounter the extrinsic curvature components:

\begin{equation}
K_{\tau\tau} = -n_{\mu}a^{\mu}
\\
K_{\phi\phi} = - \Gamma^{\mu}_{\phi\phi}n_{\mu}
\end{equation}

However, I am not understanding how to compute the jump after having the expression for the extrinsic curvature. How do you compute this explicitly for any two spacetimes metrics?

Reference:

Padmanabhan's book - "Gravitation: Foundations and Frontiers". The surface stress-energy tensor is defined on page 554.